# Onelogin Token Unauthorized error saying InvalidClaim

Tags: onelogin

While trying from Apigee, I am getting below error for validate Token API.

```
{"fault":{"faultstring":"Invalid Claim: policy(VerifyJWT.OneLogin) claim(iss)","detail":{"errorcode":"steps.jwt.InvalidClaim"}}}
```

Anyone has any idea what settings I am missing in my onelogin or application setting?

[Update]
I resolved it as found that clientId at the API gateway was not same what was being used at Front end.

Answer (score 0):

Review the value inside the token once decoded with the public key, they value encoded of ISS is incorrect.

"iss": "xyz.com/authorizationserver" this value is incorrect.